# What does the N: mean? Encountering error while installing a deb package "N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root.." Install is successful though

Tags: linux, debian, permissions

I get the error everytime I try installing it. I tried purging and reinstalling but it did not help. I also tried changing permissions like [this post here](https://askubuntu.com/a/908825) suggessted. Same result.

```
sudo apt install /home/privileged/Downloads/brave/vivaldi-stable_3.8.2259.42-1_amd64.deb 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'vivaldi-stable' instead of '/home/privileged/Downloads/brave/vivaldi-stable_3.8.2259.42-1_amd64.deb'
Recommended packages:
  adobe-flashplugin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  vivaldi-stable
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/82.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 282 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 /home/privileged/Downloads/brave/vivaldi-stable_3.8.2259.42-1_amd64.deb vivaldi-stable amd64 3.8.2259.42-1 [82.5 MB]
Selecting previously unselected package vivaldi-stable.
(Reading database ... 257032 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../vivaldi-stable_3.8.2259.42-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking vivaldi-stable (3.8.2259.42-1) ...
Setting up vivaldi-stable (3.8.2259.42-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/vivaldi-stable to provide /usr/bin/vivaldi (vivaldi) in auto mode
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.62) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.4-1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/privileged/Downloads/brave/vivaldi-stable_3.8.2259.42-1_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)
```

Running a debian 10 with xorg and xfce4.

Comment: If it installed successfully then chances are it is just information. I suspect that it is just saying that normally the package manager would want to download the package itself and sandboxed as another user, but as you gave it the file then it was "unsandboxed". It's basically saying "I didn't download this, some random did and I can't validate where it came from so any security risks are on you." Mostly a guess (I don't use debian) hence a comment.

Comment: It’s probably _N_ as in _Notice_

Comment: @DanielB What are these notations called? I know there is another one which goes as "W:" I'd like to read more about these but I couldn't find anything since I had no keyword in mind. I tried "bash error messages" on duckduckgo but nothing.

Comment: Indeed, `N: ` designates a notice, not that something actually went wrong. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590027/what-does-the-error-line-prefix-w-mean-like-from-apt-get-or-other-similar

Comment: Thanks! exacly what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be an informational warning only. From [Unix SE: What does the error line prefix w mean like from apt get or other similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/590027/what-does-the-error-line-prefix-w-mean-like-from-apt-get-or-other-similar)

> `N` is for notices. A notice is something that the program wants you to be aware of but that is not a warning. A typical notice from `apt` is `N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it`.

Your specific error message

> N: Download is performed unsandboxed as root as file '/home/privileged/Downloads/brave/vivaldi-stable_3.8.2259.42-1_amd64.deb' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

Appears to be stating that your download was performed as `root` and as such the sandboxed user (`_apt`) that `apt` uses to perform the checks/download on it prior to extraction and installation could not access it.

It is not really an error but a notice that the system could not verify the package it was installing and is just making you aware there there is something outside of the "normal" going on.